# How to get map of all properties in Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

Assume that we have a `Spring 5+` application.

How to get a collection of all properties specified in `application-[env]` files? It is also interesting to figure out the origin profile of each property.

I suppose there should be a standard way to do it, but did not manage to find any mentions in the web.

Comment: You can inject Environment object and use the getPropertySources() on it. See AbstractEnvironment.

Comment: you can have look at these resources: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MapPropertySource.html, https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to get `AbstractEnvironment` from Spring application context, and walk through its `EnumerablePropertySource` sources, discovering all property names, and then get property value by name from the environment.

```
AbstractEnvironment environment = getFromContext() /*i.e. Autowired*/;

var propsStream =
    environment
        .getPropertySources().stream()
        .flatMap(ps -> {
          if (ps instanceof EnumerablePropertySource) {
            return Arrays.stream(((EnumerablePropertySource<?>) ps).getPropertyNames());
          } else {
            return Stream.empty(); // or handle differently 
          }
        })
        .distinct()
        .map(name -> Tuple.of(name, environment.getProperty(name)));

// here Tuple is a dummy class for holding (name, value)
```